# Ui-router state definition with Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create SPA with angular and TypeScript. I'm stucked with problem that seems to be trivial but hours of serfing internet results in nothing.

Application.ts

```
/// <reference path='_all.ts' />

module app {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app.controllers',['ui.router'])
        .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('review', {
                    url: "/review",`enter code here`
                    templateUrl: "assets/html/review.html",
                    controller: 'ReviewCtrl'
                })
                .state('games', {
                    url: "/games",
                    templateUrl: "assets/html/games.html"//,
                    //controller: 'controllers.GamesCtrl'
                })
                .state('rewards', {
                    url: "/rewards",
                    templateUrl: "assets/html/rewards.html"//,
                    //controller: 'controllers.RewardsCtrl'
                })
                .state('profile', {
                    url: "/profile",
                    templateUrl: "assets/html/profile.html"//,
                    //controller: 'controllers.ProfileCtrl'
                })
        }])
        .controller('ReviewCtrl', ReviewCtrl)
        .controller('GamesCtrl', GamesCtrl)
        .controller('RewardsCtrl', RewardsCtrl)
        .controller('ProfileCtrl', ProfileCtrl)


}
```

ReviewCtrl.ts

```
module app {
    'use strict';

    export class ReviewCtrl {

        public static $inject = ['$scope','$stateParams'];

        constructor(private $scope,
                    private $stateParams)
        {
                console.log($stateParams);

        }
    }
}
```

ui-view change works successfully, but adding controller to state object resulted in "[ng:areq] Argument 'ReviewCtrl' is not a function, got undefined" exception.

Tried to exclude states in .js file, configuring 'app.controllers' module, but result was the same.

I have a guess that Typescript wrapped controllers with something, but I've tried 'app.controllers.ReviewCtrl', 'app.ReviewCtrl', 'controllers.ReviewCtrl' and I'm still here.

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS doesn't wrap your controller names. 
I had the same kind of problem that you describe and solved it by moving the TS-file with the config function to the end of the javascript (JS) file (compilation order).
You can do this be adding a `/// Reference...` (dependency) to the files containing your controller classes. To be sure, also move the angular.module(..).controller(..) statements to the corresponding TS-files where your controller class is located so they get executed before the config.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching the definition of .config() and .controller()? I don't see anything wrong, but it could be somewhere else. It can also be that you did not define the controller in _all.ts for instance.